# Imports for Maven generated code

Tags: android, maven

I'm using Maven to generate code from a SOAP web server by wsdl file.

My issue : The generated code cannot compile because of bad imports.
All the 'fr.norsys.asoape.xml' links cannot be resolved.

My pom.xml contains these lines:

```
<properties>
    <asoape.version>1.1</asoape.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
    <artifactId>asoape-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${asoape.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-soap-stub</goal>
             </goals>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>

<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtime-library</artifactId>
    <version>${asoape.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/runtime-library-1.1-sources.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to tdrury's advice, now that I use my own package, Eclipse can resiolve "fr.norsys.asoap.xml.binding.annotation"!!! But not XmlType, XmlElement, XmlRootElement... they are all parts of this package.

How is this possible? Knowing a package but not his content?

Comment: It would help if you included the classes/packages with the bad import.  If you take the fully qualified class name of one of the missing classes and go to maven central (http://search.maven.org/), click Advanced Search, put your fully qualified class name in the "Classname" field and search, it will locate the artifact for that class.  Then include that artifact as a dependency in your POM.  Rinse and repeat until all classes are resolved.

Comment: Ok thanks to you i've found the package to be imported and it is now included in my project. I can importe it by hand, but maven don't.
I edit my question with the new version of my POM file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I can't edit my first message...
Here is the POM

```
<properties>
    <asoape.version>1.1</asoape.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
    <artifactId>asoape-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${asoape.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-soap-stub</goal>
             </goals>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>

<dependency>
        <groupId>fr.norsys.asoape</groupId>
        <artifactId>runtime-library</artifactId>
        <version>${asoape.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: systemPath should point to the jar itself, not just the directory the jar is in.

Comment: Yes I figured it out.
But the issue is still there